# SQL - Count and sorted by one column

Tags: sql, ms-access

Need help on getting the count out for a Table in Access and grouping them by that particular type.

Example, I have this table

[image: Table]

I need it to output in a query into this:

[image: Query Output]

Answer (score 0):

You need conditional aggregation as follows:

```
select itemname, itemtype,
       count(case when building = 'A' then 1 end) as totalA,
       count(case when building = 'B' then 1 end) as totalB,
       count(case when building = 'C' then 1 end) as totalC
  from your_table
group by itemname, itemtype
order by itemname, itemtype, totalA desc, totalB desc, totalC desc
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of *condition aggregation*.  In MS Access, the syntax is:

```
select itemname, itemtype,
       sum(iif(building = 'A', 1, 0)) as totalA,
       sum(iif(building = 'B', 1, 0)) as totalB,
       sum(iif(building = 'C', 1, 0)) as totalC
from t
group by itemname, itemtype
order by itemname, itemtype;
```